# i cant explain 1215 error in mysql

Tags: mysql

im trying to create this table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `unidad`;
CREATE TABLE `unidad` (
  `id_uni` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `nom_uni` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_uni`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

but for some reason throw me error 1215... i cant explain why

Comment: you should make that `id_uni` an AI'd column, btw.

Comment: did you Google that error? it's foreign key constraint error.

Comment: i google it many times i cant find a answer....

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE unidad;

Comment: why SHOW? i cant create it yet